# Meaning of "the largest proportion of patients"

Tags: phrase-meaning

[From a medical paper](https://ojrd.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13023-020-01379-8):

> Improvements in motor development, cognitive functions, muscle tone abnormalities (hypotonia, poor head control, hypertonia) and epileptic seizures were reported in **the largest proportion of patients**.

I wonder about the meaning of this phrase.

Could it be that this "largest proportion" only equals, say, 30% of the overall studied population of patients, but due to it being "the largest portion united by the alleviation of the same set of symptoms", it would still qualify as the "largest proportion", with other "portions" (united by alleviation of a different set of symptoms) being smaller?

Or am I overthinking this, and this basically means that the majority of patients experienced alleviation of these symptoms?

Comment: In my opinion, it could mean both "the largest proportion of (positively affected) patients" and "the largest proportion of (all) patients". I am tilting toward the former since the sentence is about the positive effects, and negatively affected patients are mentioned in next paragraphs. However, if the treatment is overwhelmingly successful, "the largest proportion of (all) patients" is more probable.

Comment: The text is badly written. Almost certainly "the largest proportion" does ***not*** mean "the majority, most", because if that was the case they'd have used one of those alternatives (or something equally "unambiguous"). But unless we're told exactly how the cases were divided up into different categories, it's pretty meaningless to be told that the "largest" category had certain experiences. There could have been 100 people in the study - divided into 99 groups, within which only ***two*** people reported the same experience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with your analysis. Let's say 40% experienced (A), 30% experienced (B), 20% experienced (C), and 10% experienced (D). I would say "the largest proportion experienced (A)" because 40 is the biggest number, even though it is less than 50% (and therefore you couldn't say "the majority experienced (A)").

Comment: But what are these experiences B, C, D? There's no mention in the cited text of any groups other than the one that experienced [all of?] the *specific* combination of reactions.